# Austrian: What is the phrase that sounds like "Da die so" and "da ma' so" in the context "it's completed/ we're all done"?

Tags: dialect, austrian

I'm living in Austria at the moment. I keep hearing people saying something that sounds like "Da die so". I mistook it for "daddys home" the first few times I heard it. I've also heard "da ma so".

These must be dialect or at least shortened words, but I can't figure out what they are saying exactly. From the context it is something like it's completed / we're all done.

Does anybody know?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you said in which of the 9 states of Austria or in which region you heard it. There are big regional differences between the dialects spoken in Austria. And in larger cities (Vienna, Graz, Linz) there is also a clear difference between social groups (workers vs. high society).

Comment: Tirol. Overheard in offices.

Comment: Ah yes, the joys of the southern dialects...

Comment: Repeatedly thinking you were hearing "daddy's home" in offices must have been quite funny and confusing to you!

Comment: Answers given so far all tend to variations of "let's do it" (future) which doesn't exactly fit to your assumed context (past). There are expressions in the german language that sound almost the same to someone not knowing on which detail to listen, but differ a lot in what they mean. The best and most robust solution is to ask someone who has just said this. Then tell us what it meant, that would be nice to know.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'm just pleased I didn't take it at face value and start saying "Daddy's home" around the office :D

Comment: LOL... that would have been too funny... I've heard some humorous language mix-ups, and that would be a good one.  It's like discovering you were singing the wrong song lyrics for years.

Comment: Captain Picard in bavarian dialect synchronisation: "Dans as so!" ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you hear as "Da die so" is in fact

> Tat i so = Täte ich so

Or with some more words:

> Des tat i a so = Das täte ich auch so

It means:

> This is how I would do it.

---

What you hear as "da ma so" is in fact

> tamma so = tun wir so

In many Bavarian dialects (to which almost all Austrian dialects belong) lenis and fortis consonants often sound the same, so it's hard to tell *t* and *d* apart from each other. And also very often words are joined together, so that *"tan + ma"* (*"tun + wir"*) become one word: *"tamma"*

The phrase "tamma so" is often meant as:

> tamma hoit so ois ob = tun wir eben so als ob

and it means

> let's behave as if

An alternative meaning of German *»tun wir so«,* independent from the dialect, is

> let's do it this way.

This strongly depends on the context. This ambiguity is not a speciality of any dialect, it exists also in standard German.

Comment: Kamma so lasse.

Comment: @userunknown: Das kling schwäbisch. Im Osten Österreichs wäre das: "Kau ma sou loosn." Das *u* im Diphthong *ou* ist ungefähr einen Ganzton tiefer als das *o* und deutlich leiser, aber doch hörbar. Weil es so leise ist, wird es in der Verschriftlichung oft nicht wiedergegeben (Es gibt keine Rechtschreibung für Dialekte). Die Schreibweise *»so«* hat auch den Vorteil, dass Leute, für die der Dialekt eine Fremdsprache ist, trotzdem erkennen können, um welches Wort es sich handelt. Leider entsteht dann aber der falsche Eindruck, das Dialektwort würde gleich ausgesprochen wie im Standarddeutsch.

Comment: You offer *"let's behave as if"* as a possible approximation of "tamma so" while @Vulcano's answer interprets it as *"that's how we will do it"*. Those two meanings seem to be quite far apart and to me (an ignorant German speaker from the North) the second one sounds more plausible, also fitting the given context better. Would you say that the other interpretation is (also) correct?

Comment: @Emil same phrase different meaning. Depending on the context: "Tun wir so als ob wir Besucher wären" (Damma so als ob...) -> Lets behave as if we are visitors vs. after a meeting: "you take action A I will do B" Answer: "Passt, damma so" -> Thats how we will do it.

Comment: "Damma so" meaning "that's how we will do it" might be the correct observation here, because I heard that when a manager was explaining a project structure to the boss, and at the end both seemed to say exclaim "damma so".

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: Des damma imma so. Des hamma scho imma so dan.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this is a dialect. "Da ma so" is the short form for "So machen wir es" which translates roughly to "That's how we will do it"

I can't however decipher "Da die so".

Comment: "Da die so" could be "Dad i so" or "Täte ich so" --> "Würde ich so tun"

Comment: Would you indeed spell "Da ma" with a space in-between or did you take over OP's spelling?

Comment: One would hardly spell it 'da ma so' , unless you want to emphasise dialect. 'Tun wir so' would be standard German and just pronounced that way

Comment: @planetmaker I'm not sure whether you're responding to my comment, but my question concerns the usual conventions for spelling this dialectic expression. Hubert's answer confirms my supposition already, though.

Answer (score 6):

As others have already explained, "Däd i so" and "Damma so" translate to

> Däd i so. = Täte ich so. = Würde ich so machen.
> Damma so. = Tun wir so. = Machen wir so.

To provide a bit of context and help you understand dialect phrases on your on, I created a small dictionary of commonly shortened expressions. It includes mostly pronouns and variations of "tun", "gehen" and "sein". With that in mind, it shouldn't be too hard to decipher most dialect speech.

Pronouns

> ich = i, ie
> sie = se
> wir = mir, ma, mr
> ein = a
> mein = mei, moi, ma
> dein = dei, da
> sein = sei, sa
> deren = dennr

Variations of "tun"

> täte = däd
> tust du = tusch
> tun wir = tamma, damma, demmr
> tun sie = danse, dense

Variations of "gehen"

> gehst du = gosch
> geht es = gods
> gehen wir = gamma, gammr, gemmr

Variations of "sein"

> bin ich = benni
> bist du = bisch
> ist er = issr
> ist sie = isse
> ist es = ischs
> sind wir = samma, sammr, semmr
> seid ihr = sans, sands, seids, seidr
> sind sie = sanse, sense

Comment: This is very useful, thanks.
The dialect is SO STRONG. I struggle enough with German. Adding Tirolean on top is a nightmare.  So just to check, "damma so" means "that's how we will do it" and "däd i so" means "that's how I would do it?

Comment: Yes, your translations are correct. A conversation like "Däd i so. - Damma so." translates to "That's how I would do it. - Okay, let's do it that way." (@James)

Comment: As someone living in Klagenfurt and also struggling with the dialect, I also thank you! This is useful!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have answered another possibility could be the following:

When you understood

- "Da die so" and
- "da ma' so"

it was in reality

- "Dad i **sogn**" ("Täte ich sagen") and
- "Dan ma **sogn**" ("Täten wir sagen").